# SHS field is not showing in drupal 7 MEFIBS

Tags: views

I am using [Drupal 7 MEFIBS](https://www.drupal.org/project/mefibs) module, it will help to add more exposed filter blocks.

But, in this case, [SHS filed](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) not showing.

Needs to configure anything in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try using [MEFIBS Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mefibs) and 
i think This module is not compatible with [SHS Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs).

BUT Here is another solution of your problem.

if you need multiple instances of "views exposed filter blocks" or any other block then I suggest you to use [multiblock Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiblock)

following is the method for configuring multiple block instances.

1) install module [multiblock Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiblock).

2) Go to Structure->Blocks, on the Blocks page there will be an INSTANCES Tab click on it.

3) Give a title to your new instance Block and then select the block you want to create another instance of, from the "Block type" list box.

4) Click on Save

5) Now go to blocks page and find your newly created block instance in the "Disabled blocks" list and configure it in any region, any page you want.

Comment: What did you do? share your knowledge with us.

Comment: Thanks for response. I did one more simple trick without adding any extra module because already my site has around 35+ contributed modules, I don't want to make my site too slow. 
My trick is here;

 1. Make exposed filter as block.
 2. Enable in one region and mention visibility settings.
 3. Then print that region wherever you want.

 :)